# Expandable list view and arraylist

Tags: android

I am using a JSON object array list for displaying data. Now I want to use an expandable list view in which the data is classified according to date in the object. how to classify the child list according to the date.

I am accessing a JSON object and storing it in an array list. It consist of pick up date and passenger details. I want to sort and make an expandable list view consisting of date in the mainlist and passenger details in the sublist sorted according to the date.

Some objects have same booking date, so they need to be clubbed under one.

Comment: You should reconsider your asking style.

Comment: So have you tried to club it together?

Comment: Actually in my api succes i get a array list of the comprised datas ie passenger details. so i want to create an expandable listview using date in the main list and rest of details in child. how to implement that ??